# Writing and reading json in Go (Golang)

Tags: json, go

So, say I have some articles in JSON.

```
{"articles": [{"title": "This is an awesome post.", "content": "How amazing is this article actually?"}, {"title": "Asking a question on StackOerflow", "content": "It's very easy."}]}
```

So I want to read the articles in their order i.e. This is an awesome post, then Asking a question on StackOverflow. Then I have to edit or write to them in order, so when I have a new post it will be:

```
{"articles": [{"title": "New Post", "content": "Content"},{"title": "This is an awesome post.", "content": "How amazing is this article actually?"}, {"title": "Asking a question on StackOerflow", "content": "It's very easy."}]}
```

Or updating:

```
{"articles": [{"title": "New Post", "content": "Content of new post"},{"title": "This is an awesome post.", "content": "How amazing is this article actually?"}, {"title": "Asking a question on StackOerflow", "content": "It's very easy."}]}
```

I intend to manipulate articles by their titles, but I haven't been able to get such manipulation in Go (the writing and updating). Can you help me out?

I have been able to get reading with 2 interfaces, but I don't know how to write, update.

```
type Articles struct {
    Article []Article
}

type Article struct {
    Title   string
    Content string
}
```

Comment: http://blog.golang.org/json-and-go should help.

Comment: Thanks, but I thought Marshal returns a json string, so I just need to figure out how to embed it in the array.

Comment: If you're successfully decoding your JSON, then add/modify your data and encode it again (calling json.Marshal), what's the problem?

Comment: Try showing us the code that failing to Marshal, and the output you're seeing.

Comment: I've decided to create an array with a length of +1 and just add some json using the interface, going to post the code tomorrow

Comment: user2563892: by your replies so far, it sounds like you might be slightly confused at JSON and its role here.  Treat JSON as an external encoding: don't think about manipulating JSON when you're dealing with your internal data structures.  When you've got a slice of Article, and you want to manipulate that slice, JSON should have **no** role whatsoever in that process.  JSON should only be involved in the boundary between the external and internal worlds: when you're absorbing input from the network, or emitting output back to the network.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach: http://play.golang.org/p/K-eYSrn1tx

I'll copy the code here for easy of viewing:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type JsonDoc struct {
    Articles []Article
}

type Article struct {
    Title   string
    Content string
}

func main() {
    s := `{"articles": [
    {"title": "This is an awesome post.", 
     "content": "How amazing is this article actually?"}, 
    {"title": "Asking a question on StackOverflow",
     "content": "It's very easy."}]}`

    doc := JsonDoc{}
    // Toy example.  In a real application, we should not ignore
    // the possibility of an error here.
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), &doc)

    fmt.Printf("Before: %#v\n", doc)

    // Note: adding to the front of a slice is a bit expensive.
    // Consider adding to the back, or use a data representation
    // that's more appropriate.
    frontArticle := Article{Title: "Another article",
        Content: "Here's its content."}
    doc.Articles = append([]Article{frontArticle},
        doc.Articles...)

    fmt.Printf("After: %#v\n", doc)

    // Toy example: in a real application, we should not ignore
    // the possibility of an error here.
    marshalled, _ := json.Marshal(&doc)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", marshalled)
}
```

You'll notice that the marshalled output is slightly different from the input in terms of the key names.  The input used lowercased keys, but our output is producing uppercased keys!  You'll need to tell the JSON encoder a bit more about the external representation so it can do the right thing at marshal time.  Here's one way to do it, using struct field tags: http://play.golang.org/p/HHeMQUcCDV

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've solved it:

```
    s := `{"articles": [{"title": "This is an awesome post.", "content": "How amazing is this article actually?"}, {"title": "Asking a question on StackOverflow", "content": "It's very easy."}]}`
    items := &Articles{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(s), items)
    theLength := len(items.Article) + 1
    newArray := make([]Article, theLength)
    newArray[0] = Article{"My New Title", "My New Content"}
    for i := 1; i < theLength; i++ {
        newArray[i] = items.Article[i-1]
    }
    newItems := &Articles{}
    newItems.Article = newArray
    //now newItems is the new interface
```

Comment: there are the builtins `append` and `copy` for these things. see [SliceTricks](https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SliceTricks) for a variety of examples, and http://blog.golang.org/slices

Comment: Also, be aware that you're using nonstandard terms.  You will want to clear those terms up to avoid confusion with the community.  Specifically: the word "interface" has a specific, technical meaning, and most folks will be very confused at the way you're using the term.  If I were to rephrase your comment, I'd say "Now newItems contains the updated slice value."